# Most useful jQuery native API functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

What are the top 5-10 most often used jQuery native API functions? *(please do not suggest jQuery() function itself as there is no doubt this is the most often used one)* If it is possible please also provide scenarious they cover.

The reason to ask this question is my attempt to create a jQuery-like API to the [Ample SDK JavaScript GUI Framework](http://www.amplesdk.com) (there it is mainly matter of re-pointing functions, thanks to all functionality implementation present). This framework has already standard APIs (DOM Level 2-3), however from what I hear, many developers do not know well DOM APIs, others don't like those APIs, but they like concise API of jQuery (both convinient functions and fluid programming practice)

Comment: Why would someone vote to close this question?

Comment: Because it's not really a question about some particular programming problem, and it wasn't "community wiki", I suspect. (I did not vote to close!) Also, you didn't explain very well why you'd like to gather these opinions. Are you writing your own framework?  Writing an article about jQuery?  Knowing that might help guide people to give you more useful answers.

Comment: @Pointy I added clarification, agree with your concerns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find I'm using .val, .attr, .addClass, .removeClass, .hasClass, .hover, .click the most.

.val / .attr / .hasclass I use to identify pre-set values. I usually use custom attributes on elements, and getting them back with attr is great. Like storing if I've already pre-loaded content of an element. The rest is pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and it's equivalents (post, get, etc) are invaluable when making AJAX calls.

DOM read/write functions `val` and `attr` are also quite useful, but one of the reasons that jQuery's DOM functions are so useful is not necessarily the functions themselves (other than the fact they are cross-platform) but that [jQuery's selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) are such a powerful means of working with the DOM.

Comment: jQuery's selectors API is the jQuery() (or $ alias) function itself, I asked in the question not name this function as it is clear it is most useful. Thank your for the rest of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I use .animate, .hide and .show a whole lot. Very easy to use and gives the website the little extra if you add values to hide and show :)

Answer (score 0):

There are several different useful jQuery functions that you'll use on many websites. Here is a list of the top 10 and examples of how to implement them: [10 Most Useful jQuery Function For Your Website - WebDeveloperPost.com](http://webdeveloperpost.com/Articles/10-most-useful-jQuery-functions-for-your-website.aspx)