# Can I get a list of words and definitions that javascript programmers commonly use?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for words that will help me read jquery's API. I have tried looking up definitions but I want to know the most commonly used ones.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you looking for something like this,

a. https://gist.github.com/azat-co/5898111

b. [Most useful jQuery native API functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3365413/most-useful-jquery-native-api-functions)

if not, please elaborate your question.

Comment: This is very helpful, but not exactly what I am looking for. I am looking for the definition of words like listener, DOM, and iterate. Basically words that describe how the API functions work.

Comment: I am sure other developers will come up with more words but, here are few from my experience, 1. Event 2. Callback 3. Function 4. Trigger 5. select 6. Object 7. append 8. empty 9. document ready 10. css class 11. scope 12. variables 13. data 14. selector

Comment: Thanks, that will do for now.